# Uninstalling IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

Installed IE9 (9.0.7930.16406) on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Went to uninstall it, clicked 'uninstall' in add/remove programs, it removed the entry from the add/remove list, then did nothing else! Am I stuck with IE9 forever?

Comment: Are you wanting to downgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features choose the "Turn Windows Features on or off" and see if it's in that list.

Comment: Yes, uninstalling the Windows update in the Control Panel will remove IE9 and restore IE8. No need for Revo. =P